# Universal Image Loader not show images after remove internet

Tags: android, image, universal-image-loader

I found a problem using UIL. Steps to show error:

- I download pictures on a screen
- I remove internet
- I'll be right back
- And I go to the screen where I had downloaded the images.

The images are not displayed. But if I restart internet and get back into the screen, the images are displayed.

Is there any option to correct this error? thanks

Configuration:

```
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.imagen)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.imagen)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.imagen)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .build();
```

Comment: You mean that they are in the disk cache but they dont display without internet connection? Or without wifi connection? Or are they re-downloaded the second time? (You only said 'display' but what exactly is happening?). Please check the disk for those images.

Comment: @greenapps I download the images and they are displayed. But if I remove internet (3G, wifi...), I go back and I return to download images screen, only the image onFail is displayed.

Comment: That is not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem. May your cache is clearing when you close application .

See My Configuration this might help you because at My side its Working.

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE_SAFE)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                .build();
```